# Debugging in IntelliJ of AKS application run on JBoss disconnects with no reason

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, jboss, azure-aks

I have my application deployed on AKS cluster. The application is run on JBoss application server. It is run on the image that is based on *registry.access.redhat.com/jboss-eap-7/eap71-openshift* image. I want to be able to debug this application from IntelliJ.

I added variable DEBUG set to "true" to Dockerfile:

```
ENV DEBUG "true"
```

I also exposed port 8787 in the yaml deployment configuration. I try to debug application from IntelliJ, configuring remote application (I paste in the host IP and port 8787).

yaml deployment configuration looks as follows:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
    name: myapp
spec:
    replicas: 1
    strategy:
        rollingUpdate:
            maxSurge: 1
            maxUnavailable: 1
    template:
        metadata:
            labels:
                app: myapp
        spec:
            containers:
                - name: myapp
                  image: myacr.azurecr.io/myapp:wojtek
                  ports:
                  - containerPort: 8080
                  - containerPort: 8787
                  imagePullPolicy: Always
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
    name: myapp
spec:
    type: LoadBalancer
    sessionAffinity: ClientIP
    ports:
    - port: 8080
      name: http
    - port: 8787
      name: debug
    selector:
        app: myapp
```

I can see in the logs of JBoss that until I connect with JBoss there is information:

```
Debugger failed to attach: timeout during handshake
```

Then I connect with debugger and get information in IntelliJ that debugger is connected. Unfortunately, it doesn't catch anything and after ca. 10-15 seconds it gets disconnected.

What is the reason? Has anyone of you ever debugged application run on AKS cluster? Thank you in advance!

**EDIT:**

There is my debug configuration:

[image: debug configuration]

Comment: May i have the debug config settings u try in Intellij Idea

Comment: @NipunaPriyamal I edited my post in order to add settings you requested